# Power BI: latest date based on values in other columns

Tags: date, filter, powerbi

I would like to display latest date based on values on other columns.
I have data in excel and would like to display value in powerbi.
Based on the data below I would like to show when Ania Started A. This date should be displayed always without additional filters set manually.

| Date | Status | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-05 | Started B | Kasia |
| 2023-03-01 | Not started B | Ania |
| 2023-02-21 | Not started A | Magda |
| 2023-01-01 | Started A | Ania |

I do not know how to filter data based on another column I only know how to add additional filters but this is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a measure like this, which will give you the last date where `Ania` has status `Started A` no matter what filters you have selected.

```
Latest Ania Started A = 
CALCULATE ( 
    MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ),
    ALL ( 'Table' ),
    'Table'[Status] = "Started A",
    'Table'[Name] = "Ania"
)
```